# Learning is kind of stopped

Tags: job-search, job-offer, job-change

I am new in my professional field and have a hard feeling that my learning has stopped.

I have to do everything on my own, since my senior who provided most of the help has left the company. I can't receive help from this senior anymore and when I get stuck in my code it takes me days to figure out what the problem is.

Now the thing is, I want to change company to get better learning opportunity but I am unable to find with my 7 months experience in magento. I am from Pakistan and am ready to move to another city. What should I do?

Comment: `have a hard felling that my learning has stoped`.. you what?

Comment: You got this job with what you had before. Now you have that plus 7 months of experience. What is preventing you from finding a different job?

Comment: You are very definitely learning. Problem analysis is an important and useful skill.

Comment: in my filed magento, took me days to figure out what is the problem behind the error can't identify whether i am using good approach to solve my code problem because no one here to tell me that i am using good approach or making code hard @sourvac

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about the environment in Pakistan, but you found *this job* and now you have actual work experience *plus* whatever got you your current job.

> I don't have my senior from whom I can get help and when I get stuck in my code it took me days to figure out what the problem is.

That can be frustrating, we've all been there.  The good news is that the more you learn how to find your own answers the easier it will get, because as you are searching for the answer to X you will learn (or partially learn) other related things.  I.e. when you have no help, you'll learn a little more than you intended to for each problem you solve on your own - if you had asked someone you would have gotten only the actual answer you were seeking.

Comment: yeah that's the problem i get frustrated

Comment: @AsadUllah We all do. That's why your job pays better than 'minimum wage'